# Unity ads initialization failed: internal_error - unity ads sdk failed to initialize due to environment check failed

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityads

I'm having an error only when running on Android in unity.

This is the error:

```
Unity ads initialization failed: internal_error - unity ads sdk failed to initialize due to environment check failed
```

I used the correct keys to initialize my ads on android.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: I advise you to ask the question here too (https://forum.unity.com/forums/unity-ads-user-acquisition.67/): it seems that in several chats Unity employees answer directly

Comment: @Francesco-FL Thank you, I've asked it there too

Answer (score 2):

This error is most likely due to an outdated version of the unity ads package.
Please try removing the current version you have and installing the latest through the unity package manager. Chances are you will need to update some code as there have been some breaking changes in the past.

Comment: I've fixed it by changing my ads initializer script completely. It works now